# SUM a value from a table which is linked to a second table via a third table

Tags: mysql, join

Here is a simplified list of the tables & their columns:

```
Table: Sub_Jobs
Columns: ID

Table: Cargo
Columns: ID | Size

Table: Cargo_Assignment
Columns: ID | Sub_Job_ID | Cargo_ID
```

Cargo is created and given a Size value (numerical). It's then assigned to a Sub Job by creating a row in the Cargo_Assignment table.

I need to return a list of all Sub_Jobs IDs and the SUM of Cargo.Size for cargo assigned to that Sub_Job (via the Cargo_Assignment table).

Here is some sample data:

```
Table: Sub_Jobs
ID
 1
 2 
 3

Table: Cargo
ID Size
 1  3.5
 2  1.2
 3  0.5
 4  1.8

Table: Cargo_Assignment
ID  Sub_Job_ID  Cargo_ID
 1           1         3  
 1           1         1 
 1           2         4
```

And the required query result:

```
Sub_Job_ID  Total_Size
         1           4 
         2         1.8
         3           0
```

MySQL is very much my weakness, and I'm really struggling with this one. I've tried for several hours to get this working, with different joins & sub queries etc but I just can't wrap my head around it.

This is one of the queries I've tried, but it is only returning one result:

```
SELECT Sub_Jobs.ID, SUM(Cargo.Size) as Total_Size
FROM Sub_Jobs
INNER JOIN Cargo_Assignment ON Cargo_Assignment.Sub_Job_ID = Sub_Jobs.ID
INNER JOIN Cargo ON Cargo.ID = Cargo_Assignment.Cargo_ID
```

Comment: You need a [GROUP BY clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html): `GROUP BY Sub_Jobs.ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query logic is really close.  You need `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT sj.ID, SUM(c.Size) as Total_Size
FROM Sub_Jobs sj INNER JOIN
     Cargo_Assignment ca
     ON ca.Sub_Job_ID = sj.ID INNER JOIN
     Cargo c
     ON c.ID = ca.Cargo_ID
GROUP BY sj.ID;
```

Note that you don't need the `JOIN` to `Sub_Jobs`, because the field is in `Cargo_Assignment`:

```
SELECT ca.Sub_Job_ID, SUM(c.Size) as Total_Size
FROM Cargo_Assignment ca INNER JOIN
     Cargo c
     ON c.ID = ca.Cargo_ID
GROUP BY ca.Sub_Job_ID;
```

Comment: First part worked perfectly, thank you - I thought it may have something to do with a Group By. The second amendment however is throwing an error: "near 'ON c.ID = ca.Cargo_ID GROUP BY ca.Sub_Job_ID ". Just letting you know.